# MUI v5 theme not working, except with link

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, npm-link

I'm working on a library with MUI v5. The problem is I'm importing this library to a React project (React v17.0.1) which uses MUI v4.

The problem is that the MUI theme is not working on my components, except if I use my library doing `npm link`.

Any ideas?

I'm using Typescript ^3.7.5.

Comment: Do you use TypeScript?

Comment: Yes, i'm using Typescript ^3.7.5

Comment: Themes between V4 and V5 are not compatible. Please read:
https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#theme-structure

Comment: Seems logic ! But why is my theme working when I am doing a npm link ?